# Search in elasticSearch using alias name

Tags: search, elasticsearch, alias

I have an alias pointing to two indices. I would like to use the alias name to search the documents rather than passing two index names and getting the results.

Example :

Like this : SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("alias")

Not like this : SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("index1", "index2")

Comment: It works the same way with an alias, just try your first statement and you'll see.

Answer (score 7):

Just replace the index name with alias name and work with it the same way.